# React-native video upload android crashing

Tags: android, video, react-native

I am trying to upload video files from react-native to a node js server. The app is supposed to capture video from camera, upload it and meanwhile capture next video. It is working fine for IOS but keeps crashing/freezing for android after the first video. I am using react native [file uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-uploader) library to upload video. 
Please help.

Comment: What symptoms are you seeing suggesting that it's "crashing/freezing" (app becomes unresponsive, console.logs indicating error, etc)? When "after first video" is it "crashing/freezing" (upon completing the capturing of the video, upon initiating the upload of the 1st video, upon completing the upload of the 1st video, etc)? What have you done so far to try to debug/fix your issue?

Comment: Help me with this(kind of same)react native -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280005/react-native-camera-video-capture-unable-to-preview-and-upload-as-snapchat-vide